# Is there any way to take input from user after azure devops release creation?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

We have a scenario where some stages that are auto triggered a specific stage in our Azure DevOps release pipeline is set to trigger manually.

Now, release will be created by a user after setting all the run time variables and all the auto trigger stages will be executed without any issue.

Problem that we are facing is, we do not have option for users to change the values of run time variable/provide input **before triggering** the "manual trigger stage" **after the release creation**.

Really appreciate if anyone can help on this.

Note: We know we can change the values by **editing the release** but due to policy limitation all users are not able to edit the release. Hence, looking for alternative.

Thank you!

Comment: i think its not possible to change variable -without editing release- after release creation.

Comment: I checked your question and  answer . it's a good way to follow his steps to try it first. If the solution is indeed helpful, you could mark it as a correct answer to let other one know the solutions. If you have any questions and need help, we are happy to help you.